# Creating a simple webservice in nodejs

Tags: web-services, node.js, rest

I need to create a simple rest based webservice in node.js I already know only how to consume the already exposed ones.I used http  module for that.Any suggestion on how to create a webservice will be much helpful

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Expressjs](http://expressjs.com/guide.html), it's the most common web framework to make REST Api. Check this stackoverflow question which provides a lot of [good resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8144214/learning-express-for-node-js). Have a look at this [tutorial](http://www.hacksparrow.com/express-js-tutorial.html) too.

If you need something more evolved I recommend you [CompoundJS](http://compoundjs.com/) which will help you to give a structure to your code.

Answer (score 1):

Hey heres something that i tried its really simple.Below is the code

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var data="<Bank><rows>10</rows></Bank>"
console.log(data);
app.get('/Dynamic', function(req, response) {
response.contentType('application/xml');
console.log('listening');
response.send(data);
});
console.log('server will be listening on: 1360' );
app.listen(1360);
```

Hope this helps .

Answer (score 0):

we can use this code

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.post('/login', function(req, res) {

    res.send('Got the data');
});
app.listen(3002);
console.log('Listening on port 3002...');
```